# Saving JWTs to memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

Probably an easy question to answer, but I've seen a few recommendations to store JWTs on the client side in memory rather than local storage (+then combine with refresh tokens) and was going to give it a try.

I'm not making an spa / using a frontend framework like react, so doesn't that cause problems with the idea of storing the token in memory, as it'll be wiped every time I navigate to another page?

Thanks

*EDIT: So given that I can't store the token in memory, my next best options look like they are storing the token in local storage or as an httponly cookie. The former seems (relatively) insecure, and the latter is going to cause me a headache (I think) because I use `passport.authenticate()` to verify my token

Given that there's not going to be any sensitive information for user accounts, and I only really care about securing the admin account, I'm tempted to just force a login on any route that creates or deletes data.

Comment: Where did you see these recommendations, and why was this recommendation been made?

Comment: Actually, the ideal usage of the JWT pattern is to _not_ store the tokens either in memory or local storage.

Comment: @Brad https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/  was one, but I've definitely seen others. And as to why, I guess to protect against xss? I dunno, I've seen such a wide range of opinions on the subject, from 'if you've got xss problems, session data is the least of your worries', to 'store the jwt in memory and refresh token in httponly cookies', and tbh I don't know quite where to fall on it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - nooo, not another option xD

Have you any links or resources I might be able to follow? I've implemented Passport-jwt, and just want to make sure it's not wide open to attacks. There's nothing particularly important about the data I store, other than that it isn't lost or messed with (ie the admin account is secure)

Comment: A JWT is intended to be like a passport, such that a user need only present its JWT to get authenticated.  As a consequence, there is no longer a need to store the user session on the server side.  So, the server can become stateless.

Comment: Yeah, I've got that all set up thankfully :) My question was refering to storing the jwt on the client side. Hang on, I'll edit my OP

Comment: That recommendation implies an SPA architecture. In addition it implies an SPA architecture that will log you out if you open links in a new tab or refresh the page like a lot of banking portals. If you are not doing SPA then you can't save tokens in RAM

Comment: @slebetman yup, that's what I thought. So I guess my best option is to save jwt in local storage + use a refresh token?

Comment: Not necessarily your **best** option - just one option. Another option is to store it in a cookie. With cookies you can use all the security mechanism available to you like domains, the secure flag etc. Such a thing can make your token unreadable by javascript so you can 100% manage your tokens from your server/servers without needing a session storage. For my application I prefer localstorage because my backend is on multiple domains and managing cookies get messy.

Comment: @slebetman Store the jwt in a cookie? I feel like I'm then opening myself up for a headache as I'm using Passport's jwt strategy and verification, so I wouldn't know how to combine that with a cookie. I'm really tempted right now just to change everything to a server with a template engine and use sessions xD

Comment: If you are on any concerns that if someone might snatch the token from local storage and use it, do an encryption and save it. ;)

Comment: @NickW You should store in memory on node server in cache

Comment: @NickW passport-jwt has a `jwtFromRequest` parameter that allows you to customize how the JWT token is passed from the client. Again, my point is to be aware of your options and the pros and cons of each option. I myself don't use cookies in my current project

Comment: @slebetman yeah I just found a good example using it, good to know, thanks. And yeah, I think I'm starting to side with the 'if you're vulnerable to xss, you're screwed anyway' camp, I don't think an httponly cookie is saving me. I just need to be mindful about sanitising inputs and not using obscure packages. I think I'll also force a login for every important admin action on the db. Out of interest, do you think I should keep checking admin rights as a separate check from login? IE don't return privileges for every user?